# Can't save new file from Matlab even though I definitely have write permissions

Tags: matlab, save, rhel7

I'm trying to save a .mat file in the following manner:

```
save('/path/to/file/file.mat','var1','var2');
```

I'm getting the "Cannot save /path/to/file/file.mat: Permission denied" that you typically get when the user running Matlab does not have permissions to write to the directory specified.

The problem is I ABSOLUTELY have write permissions to /path/to/file.

The output to

```
ls -l '/path/to/'
```

shows the 'file' directory as drwxrwxr-x, and belongs to group "Developers", which I am a part of.

Further proof that I have write permissions: If I cd /path/to/file/ and then create a file named 'file.mat' using vim, and THEN invoke Matlab's save as described above, it WORKS!.  If I then remove that file using a terminal and try to save from Matlab again, it FAILS!

Why might I not be able to create a new file from Matlab?

The only nuance I can think of is /path/to/file is an NFS mount on RHEL7

Comment: Can you do `!touch /path/to/file/file.mat` from within MATLAB?

Comment: Maybe MATLAB does not have write permissions?

Comment: Most odd. I would personally try to debug using `strace`, something like this: `strace -o /tmp/strace.out -f --trace=file matlab -nodisplay` and then try to save. This will generate lots of output, so just do the `save` and then quit. This _might_ give a hint as to what's going wrong...

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am denied permission to use touch to create the file

Comment: @AnderBiguri using the fileattrib matlab function results in matlab thinking it has permissions

Comment: So if you have permission to create the file when not in MATLAB, but you don’t when in MATLAB, then perhaps MATLAB is running as a different user? Note that when you do `!touch…` you’re using a new process, not the MATLAB process, but it’s a child process which inherits the MATLAB environment and user name.

Comment: When you do `!whoami` in MATLAB, do you get the right user name? It should match the name of the user you see when you do `!ls -l /path/to/file/`.

Comment: Oh, wait, reading your post again, maybe `/path/to/file/` belongs to a different user, but it’s the group’s permission you’re depending on. How are groups administered? If you do `!groups` in MATLAB, do you see the same group name listed as the one the file belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Matlab session was launched prior to myself being added to the 'Developer' group. A log out, log in, and relaunch of Matlab fixed the issue.